# Python search list according to another reference list

Tags: python, sorting

I have two lists:

```python
refList = ['INDIA', 'ALPHA','CHARLIE','BRAVO','WHISKEY','SIERRA']
sortList = ['CHARLIE','SIERRA','ALPHA', 'INDIA']
```

I want to sort `sortList` according to `refList`, i.e.:

```
result = ['INDIA', 'ALPHA','CHARLIE','SIERRA']
```

What is the most efficient way of doing this?

Comment: I did search for and try that method in the link you shared, but itdid not work for me. If you notice in that question, the two source lists are different in terms of elements within them..

X is an alphabetical list and Y is a numeric list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> nlist = [r for r in refList if r in sortList]
>>> print nlist
['INDIA', 'ALPHA', 'CHARLIE', 'SIERRA']
```

May not be the most efficient way since we search in my list for every element in reflist. This is just simple and good enough for small lists